# WCF UriTemplate for RESTful resource

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

[As mentioned in 2009](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1e581c4b-191e-4f1d-9113-b1a75b2f0282/), WCF could not differentiate the following urls to return a list of Users and a specific User:

```
/users 
/users/{id}
```

Is this still the case with WCF4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's answer is great, but I'd use:

```
[OperationContract(Name="Op1")]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "DoWork/")]
int[] DoWork();

[OperationContract(Name = "Op2")]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "DoWork/{id}")]
int[] DoWork(string id);
```

Comment: +1 Good point, WebGet is likely better than WebInvoke for REST service GETs. I am not sure what the ideal recommended pattern is for WebGet/WebInvoke

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the pattern is no different between the two except that there's no Method definition on WebGet because it's implicit. It seems that WebGet exists solely because the vast majority of web services are data providers not data receivers. Other than it's name and the fact that it implicitly implements GET, the two seem identical.

Comment: Jonathan, no. The operation contract name is not exposed in the URL, as far as I know. In fact, I never even use the Name parameter in the OperationContract attribute. I usually just put [OperationContract]. The only part that should matter for the URL is the service endpoint URL + the UriTemplate string pattern. However, since I never use the Name parameter, perhaps I am mistaken. Maybe if it's there there, it gets used in the URL. Not entirely sure, but I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now:

```
[OperationContract(Name="Op1")]
[WebInvoke(Method= "GET", UriTemplate = "DoWork/")]
int[] DoWork();

[OperationContract(Name = "Op2")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "DoWork/{id}")]
int[] DoWork(string id);
```

The important thing is that the OperationContract must have the Name= property with different names for each operation.